# Authentication with ServiceStack and more provider

Tags: authentication, service, servicestack, servicestack-auth

I state that I use ServiceStack to authenticate my services.
My problem is the following I am developing two authentication methods via credentials and via API key.
The implementation is correct but I would like some services to be authenticated through Credentials while other services through API key. Reading from documentation it seemed to me that I understood that it was enough to insert in the [Authenticate] attribute the provider parameter equal to the property Name of the reference Auth class (Credentials or API), getting [Authenticated ("apikey")] for example.
Unfortunately, implementing the example above, if I authenticate with credentials, I can call the service while I would only like this service to be called via API key.
Do you have any solutions?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Authenticate(provider)]` will check if the User is considered to be authenticated according to that Auth Provider where it calls the AuthProviders `IsAuthorized()` to verify if the session is authenticated.

If you want to mandate that a Request was authenticated using an API Key you can check for it in your Service implementation, e.g:

```
if (Request.GetSession().AuthProvider != ApiKeyAuthProvider.Name)
    throw HttpError.Forbidden("Must authenticate with API Key");
```

Comment: Thanks mythz, the name turned out to be misleading and took me astray. From documentation I thought that by putting the provider as an argument, it checked the authentication methodology. Thanks again!

Comment: This does seem really missleading indeed:/// <summary>
        /// Restrict authentication to a specific <see cref="IAuthProvider"/>.
        /// For example, if this attribute should only permit access
        /// if the user is authenticated with <see cref="BasicAuthProvider"/>,
        /// you should set this property to <see cref="BasicAuthProvider.Name"/>.
        /// </summary>